# Data structure for handling closed intervals

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was learning for the test when I spotted problem I cannot deal with:

> Design a data structure for handling (closed) intervals which 
>     will provide three operations:
>
> Insert(x,y) - add interval [x, y]
>
> Remove(x,y) - remove interval [x, y]
>
> Count(x,y) - count the number of intervals that are purely contained within the interval [x, y]
>
> x,y are integers from 1 to n. All operations can take at most time O((log n)<sup>2</sup>)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree ?

Comment: @jDourlens- Interval trees don't match the time bounds given above, and (IIRC) are static structures, meaning that they don't support dynamic insertions and deletions.

Comment: Does the Count operation count how many intervals are *purely* contained within [x, y] or how many intervals *overlap* with [x, y]?

Comment: purely contained within [x; y]

Comment: Given a static data structure, you can make it dynamic with an overhead of about log n. Just mark deletes and rebuild if more than a half are deleted. For inserts build and keep static structures of size 1, 2, 4, ..., merging smaller structures to make larger ones. You can even do this gradually to go from amortized to worst case cost. One link found from a search is http://wwwisg.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/ag/lehre/WS1112/GDS/slides/S11.pdf

Comment: What does "handling closed intervals" mean in this case? If you remove a closed interval from another closed interval the remaining part will have *open* ends by definition. Do you mean that you have to treat the ends as closed anyway?

Comment: @AndreyT: I was certain that the OP intended the intervals to be added to and removed from a *set of intervals* (that retain their individuality). You seem to have interpreted it differently: you think intervals should be merged when an overlapping interval is added and broken apart when an interval is removed from a larger, containing interval. That interpretation also makes sense. What is it, OP?

Comment: It is also interesting, but I hadn't this in mind.

Answer (score 5):

This can be solved in O(log^2 n) time and O(nlog n) space using a combination of a **[Fenwick Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree)** and a data structure based on a **[segment tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree)**, which houses an internal tree *inside each node*.  The former is used for efficiently finding and updating counts of points within a given range; the latter for efficiently finding and updating counts of segments that straddle a given point.  The basic idea is to count segment endpoints within the given query range, and then adjust for segments that cross either or both endpoints.

This algorithm is based on the observation that, for a given query range (a, b),

> nContained = (h - nStraddlingOne) / 2

where nContained is the number of intervals contained by (a, b), h is the number of interval endpoints of either kind (beginning or ending) in (a, b), and nStraddlingOne is the number of intervals that contain either only a or only b.  The "database" of intervals at any time is called D here.

A Fenwick tree allows you to count the total number of points between two integer indices (a, b) in O(log n) time, using an O(n) table.  It also permits O(log n) insertions and deletions.  We add both end points of every interval to it, and use it to calculate h in O(log n) time.

### Counting crossings

Our other data structure is very similar to a segment tree, but there are two main differences: instead of inferring the start and end points of intervals from the input set of intervals, we take the set of endpoints to be every possible integer between 1 and n inclusive, and have no "open sets" (this is to simplify the addition of new intervals later); and we store each node's interval set in a particular way.

Suppose for simplicity that n is a power of 2 (if it isn't, just pick the next biggest power of 2 -- this will cause an increase of less than n, so the time complexity won't change).  Let T be a complete binary tree that has a leaf node for each position 1 <= i <= n.  (This tree will have 2n - 1 nodes in total.)  Every leaf node represents a single position.  Every non-leaf node represents the union of the positions of all leaf nodes under it, which must form an interval having length a power of 2.  Call the interval represented by a node v Int(v).  (Note: because this binary tree is complete, it can be represented "implicitly" the same way a binary heap often is, to save space.)

To each node v of T, there corresponds a set of intervals called Span(v).  (We will only actually store their rightmost endpoints.)  Span(v) is the set of all intervals in D that

1. Contain Int(v), and
2. Do not contain Int(parent(v)).

In each vertex v, we store only the rightmost endpoints of the intervals in Span(v) in a **self-balancing binary tree** that is ordered by this end point, and in which every node is augmented with a count of descendant nodes.  **That is, every node of the "outer" tree contains an "inner" tree.**  This is necessary to enable us to efficiently calculate how many intervals completely contain a given query interval.

The fundamental query operation on a segment tree is determining the set of intervals that contains a given point x, and this is easily changed to count rather than report individual intervals.  The operation is simple: setting v to the root,

1. Add the number of intervals in Span(v) to the total.
2. If v is a leaf, then stop.
3. Otherwise, suppose the left and right children of v are u and w respectively.  If x is contained in Int(u), then recurse on u, otherwise recurse on w.

Given a query interval (a, b), the above query can be performed twice, once for a and once for b.  Set nStraddlingAtLeastOne to the sum of the counts for both queries.  Note that counting can be done in O(1) time for each node -- it is just the count field of the root node of the self-balancing binary tree storing Span(v).

### Double crossings!

The difficulty (and what eventually stymied an earlier attempt at a O(log n) algorithm that I spent some time on) is that we also need to count the number of intervals that simultaneously span *both* endpoints of the query (a, b).  To do this, we start with v at the root again, and perform a modified query for a (the starting point of the query), in which step 1 is replaced with:

1. Count the number of intervals in Span(v) having right endpoint >= b, and add it to the total.

This counting step can be performed in O(log n) time due to the self-balancing binary tree.  Since each tree level needs up to 2 of these counting operations, this is the part that pushes the time complexity up to O(log^2 n).  Set nContaining to the total from this query.  We can calculate nStraddlingOne using

> nStraddlingOne = nStraddlingAtLeastOne - nContaining

Using nStraddlingOne and the h calculated from the Fenwick tree, we can now calculate nContained according to the equation at the top.

### Adding and removing intervals

Updating is O(log^2 n) too, since updating the Fenwick tree is O(log n), and adding an interval (x, y) to the segment tree takes O(log^2 n) time using the following algorithm, starting with v at the root:

1. If (x, y) contains Int(v), then add y to the self-balancing binary tree storing the right endpoints of Span(v) and stop.
2. Otherwise, suppose the left and right children of v are u and w respectively.

   - If (x, y) overlaps Int(u), recurse on u.
   - If (x, y) overlaps Int(w), recurse on w.

The above traversal visits only O(log n) nodes in the segment tree, because each interval added will appear in the interval sets of at most 2 nodes on any tree level, for a maximum of 2log(n) space usage per interval.  Please see [the Wikipedia page on Segment Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree#Structure_description) for a proof and further explanation.  Removing an interval uses a similar algorithm.  Each insertion or removal into the self-balancing binary tree at a node takes O(log n) time, for O(log^2 n) time in total.

### Space usage

Space usage is O(nlog n), since there are O(log n) tree levels in the segment tree, each of which may require space for 2 instances of an internal tree node containing each possible endpoint.  Note in particular that even though there are O(n^2) possible distinct intervals, we store only the rightmost endpoint of each interval, so this is not a problem.  Also because we store counts, adding a second copy of an existing interval only causes counts to increase -- it does not cause any new node allocations.  Fenwick trees use only O(n) space.

Answer (score 1):

See [Range Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree). The time complexity for querying is mentioned as O(log<sup>d</sup> n + k). Here d is dimension, n is number of points stored in the tree and k is number of points **reported** by the query.

But we need only the count without reporting the points. So I think if number of children (actually number of leaves because the real points are stored in the leaves) is maintained on each node, this k can be eliminated leaving us with O(log<sup>2</sup> n). Insertion and deletion are also O(log<sup>2</sup> n).

Comment: I can see how this could be used to report all the *points* in a given range, but not how it could be used to report all the *intervals* entirely contained within a given range.

Comment: @j_random_hacker "It allows all points within a given range to be reported efficiently, and **is typically used in two or higher dimensions**" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree) - pay attention to the second part of the quote. Intervals can be represented as two dimensional points **in case** the query looks for points purely contained within the interval. If the query were to look for overlapping intervals then there would be a potential problem, though often interval data has a special property which enables that potential problem to be solved with a little trick too. See my answer.

Comment: @RolandPihlakas: I paid attention to the second part of the quote, which you had already helpfully bolded, and also read your answer, but none of these things have yet convinced me that this approach will solve the problem in the required time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

An interval tree fits here, for instance https://github.com/ekg/intervaltree/blob/master/IntervalTree.h see this code, it provides a findContained which looks O(log(n)), Apart from that deletion is more complex but surely can be done in O(log(n)) 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Deletion

Comment: But this doesn't have worst-case O(log^2 n) performance, and it doesn't support insertion in O(log^2 n) time.  I don't think this answers the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes simple sorted sets can be used:

- The intervals in data set have some known **maximum** length, 

- And additionally this maximum length is not too big when compared to the overall value range of x data points in set.

In this case it is enough to just use simple sorted set:

- Add intervals to it using only the `x dimension` of the interval.

- Query it like this: `get intervals with their x dimension in range [x', y'] and then filter out the few intervals that have their y dimension crossing the y' limit`.

Given the same above mentioned precondition on data properties of having known **maximum** length, this logic **can be extended to perform also interval-tree like queries** where the query does not ask for "data purely **contained** within the interval", but instead asks for "data **overlapping** the given interval". In such case the query would be:

- `get intervals with their x dimension in range [x' - maximum interval range, y' + maximum interval range] and then filter out the few intervals that actually are outside of requested range`.

Comment: The OP is quite clear about the required worst-case time complexity, which invalidates any solution that has to filter out an arbitrary number of (that is, O(n^2)) intervals.  For example, if all n(n-1)/2 possible ranges are in the data structure and the query (1, n/2) arrives, your algorithm takes O(n^2) time.  Needless to say, that's a lot worse than O(log^2 n).  See my answer for an algorithm that works in the required time complexity.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Please pay attention to the preconditions I specified: **"The intervals have some known maximum length. This maximum length is not too big when compared to the overall value range"**. Here I mean intervals in the data set, not intervals of query. Also please note, I am NOT claiming that the solution is universal. But in cases it is usable, the time complexity is only log(n) + constant. So might be very helpful. The constant does not depend on n. Instead it depends on the general frequency of x values divided by the (again application specific) minimum range of y - x.

Comment: The preconditions you specified make your answer irrelevant to the OP's question, which grants no such conditions on the maximum interval length and clearly asks for an algorithm that can perform each operation in O(log^2 n) time.  If you want, ask a new question and answer it yourself with the answer you have given here -- but if you allow the maximum length to be bounded by a constant k, then the O(k^2+log n)-time algorithm you give here is trivial, so such a question might not garner much outside interest.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thanks for Your clarification. The answer does not violate the conditions given by OP. Instead it highlights one special case that might well be unconsidered by the OP - or someone else looking at that topic. log time is better than log^2 time so what is there un-granted? What is trivial for You is not trivial for everyone. That is the point of this site: to enumerate various solutions to insufficiently detailed problem, or for a class of problems.

Comment: My -1 was a bit heavy-handed -- it was prompted in part by the rather loud and unconvincing claim in your first comment to me, which this answer failed to back up.  I've dropped it now.  And yes, the OP didn't explicitly rule out the possibility that interval lengths are bounded by some constant -- but then, it's impractical to expect a question asker to explicitly list every possible special case that they aren't interested in hearing about, so an answerer should assume that the asker wants a fully general answer to their question, rather than that the question is "insufficiently detailed".